# Any idea what could be causing this page to not display in IE9?

Tags: html, wordpress, iis-7, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

The page displays fine in the following:

- Chrome 21 on OSX
- FireFox 14 on OSX
- Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP VM (with Compatibility Mode turned off)

However, the page only displays the header background in Internet Explorer 9 (Windows 7 VM).  Any ideas?  The website is located [here](http://goo.gl/dVrfp) temporarily.

EDIT~  All the sub-pages are loading fine in IE9...only the homepage refuses to load.  Here is a link to a [subpage](http://goo.gl/vcQnL).

EDIT 2~  I am beginning to believe this is a server problem.  We are running an IIS7 server.  For 50% of the day, the site works wonderfully on all browsers.  Then for the other 50% of the day, IE8-9 will not display properly UNLESS you attach **index.php** at the end of the URL or **https://** at the beginning.  Any advice?  I'm thinking of starting a new topic to gain more attention but I also don't want to upset the stackoverflow community.

EDIT 3~  Turned out it wasn't a server issue (or maybe it was, but I fixed it on my end).  WP Super Cache was the culprit.  Once that plugin was disabled, problem was solved!

Comment: IE9 has a decent-ish set of developer tools built into it. have you tried using them to look under the hood?

Comment: It's not showing in IE8 either. Are you declaring all HTML5 elements in your CSS as block elements and including the HTML5shiv JS file for non-compatible browsers?

Comment: @MarcB I'm looking through the tools right now...I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for, but I will play around with this for a while and see what I can find out.

Comment: @BillyMoat Really?  I just tested it in IE8 a few minutes ago and it loaded fine!  O_o This is very odd.

Comment: @Jonathan - So are you including the HTML5 bits I mentioned?

Comment: @BillyMoat I believe all elements are declared as block elements.  Also, rather than including the HTML5Shiv I am utilizing Modernizr...do you think changing this would help?

Comment: You have quite a few html errors on the page. Fixing these may help. In particular you have a closing P tag with no opening P tag and you have a STYLE tag within the BODY. style tag should only be used within the HEAD. Use this to view the errors: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @BillyMoat That was it, the STYLE was within a blog post...I moved it into a different area and now it works.  Its not a great workaround that I'm doing but it works.

Comment: @Jonathan - Cool, I'll post that as an answer and you can accept it if that's okay. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying nearly every answer posted here, nothing seemed to be working.  So I decided to disable/re-enable all my plugins just to see if one of them was the cause...turned out WP Super Cache was the culprit.  Once this was disabled, the page has worked since!  Not exactly sure why, but I felt this needed to be posted incase anyone else has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have inspected the DOM, and it looks like IE9 renders the page up til this piece of javascript:

```
<!-- function clickIE4(){ ...
```

That's an opening comment tag which is never closed.

See the two screenshots:

This is the output of IE9 developer tools, the page is rendered only until the opening script tag that includes the above code.

[image: IE9 developer tools screenshot]

The chrome developer tools output looks like this. I guess that its parsing engine automatically closes the opening HTML comment once a closing `</script>` tag follows.

[image: Chrome developer tools screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, I just removed the offending code.  While I'm sure that helped a lot, it still hasn't helped my IE8-9 problems.  Please check my initial post because I am going to edit it right now with the new information I have since discovered.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make block level element of the html5 tags:

```
article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I included this line but it does not appear to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few html errors on the page. Fixing these may help. In particular you have a closing P tag with no opening P tag and you have a STYLE tag within the BODY. style tag should only be used within the HEAD.